# Как получить ключ и значение из AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Double, Integer>

Tags: java, map

Есть метод:

```
public Map<String, AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Double, Integer>> getCustomers(){
TreeMap<String, AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Double, Integer>> goodsList = new TreeMap<>();

            for (Map.Entry<Integer, ArrayList<String>> entry : treeMap.entrySet()) {
                if (goodsList.containsKey(entry.getValue().get(0))){
                    AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Double, Integer> sum = goodsList.get(entry.getValue().get(0));
                    AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Double, Integer> count = goodsList.get(entry.getValue().get(0));
                    goodsList.put(entry.getValue().get(0), (new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>((Double.parseDouble(entry.getValue().get(3))),(Integer.parseInt(entry.getValue().get(2))))));
                } else
                    goodsList.put(entry.getValue().get(0), (new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>((Double.parseDouble(entry.getValue().get(3))),(Integer.parseInt(entry.getValue().get(2))))));
            }
            return goodsList;
        }
```

Метод получает из TreeMap ArrayList и сравнивает, есть ли ключ в goodsList, и если да, то надо сложить имеющийся Double с новым и также с Integer. Никак не могу из AbstractMap.SimpleEntry раздельно получить Double и занести в sum, и Integer в count.

p.s.

проблему решил, на мой взгляд не совсем красиво, но работает. значения получил циклом:

```
double sum = 0;
int count = 0;
for (SimpleEntry<Double, Integer> value : goodsList.values()) {
    sum = value.getKey();
    count = value.getValue();
}
```

то есть, сейчас код выглядит так:

```
public Map<String, AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Double, Integer>> getCustomers(){
    TreeMap<String, AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Double, Integer>> goodsList = new TreeMap<>();

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, ArrayList<String>> entry : treeMap.entrySet()) {
        if (goodsList.containsKey(entry.getValue().get(0))){
            double sum = 0;
            int count = 0;
            for (SimpleEntry<Double, Integer> value : goodsList.values()) {
                sum = value.getKey();
                count = value.getValue();
            }
            goodsList.put(entry.getValue().get(0), (new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>((Double.parseDouble(entry.getValue().get(3)) + sum),(Integer.parseInt(entry.getValue().get(2))) + count)));
        } else
            goodsList.put(entry.getValue().get(0), (new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>((Double.parseDouble(entry.getValue().get(3))),(Integer.parseInt(entry.getValue().get(2))))));
    }
    return goodsList;
}
```

Comment: ничего не понятно =(

Comment: вы явно что-то делаете неправильно. опишите задачу с примерами входных данных и ожидаемым результатом, потому как разобраться в вашем коде , мягко говоря, сложно

Comment: На входе приходят данные - ФИО, заказ, сумма. Если ФИО повторяется, то надо сложить кол-во заказов и сумму заказов.

Comment: почему не создаете класс для хранения ФИО, заказа, суммы? в классе все станет на много понятнее и проще

Comment: Дмитрий, согласен про класс, но изначально начал делать через TreeMap, где в качестве значения ArrayList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не хватает репутации на комментарий, спрошу здесь. Хотя не на 100% понимаю что тут вообще написано))
Зачем циклом по всем `values` ,бегать? Если вам вам надо только с определенным ключем. А так как у вас вы получите значения sum и count по последнему ключу.
Может так надо?

```
public Map<String, AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Double, Integer>> getCustomers(){
        TreeMap<String, AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Double, Integer>> goodsList = new TreeMap<>();

        for (Map.Entry<Integer, ArrayList<String>> entry : treeMap.entrySet()) {
            if (goodsList.containsKey(entry.getValue().get(0))){

                AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Double, Integer> simpleEntry = goodsList.get(entry.getValue().get(0));
                Double sum = simpleEntry.getKey();
                Integer count = simpleEntry.getValue();

                goodsList.put(entry.getValue().get(0), (new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>((Double.parseDouble(entry.getValue().get(3)) + sum),(Integer.parseInt(entry.getValue().get(2))) + count)));
            } else
                goodsList.put(entry.getValue().get(0), (new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>((Double.parseDouble(entry.getValue().get(3))),(Integer.parseInt(entry.getValue().get(2))))));
        }
        return goodsList;
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо. Именно то, что нужно и если первую строку вашего решения я рассматривал, то как извлечь из (у вас это simpleEntry) не догадался.

Comment: Ну использовать такую структуру данных для хранения, в ОО языке... вы знаете толк в извращениях))

Comment: Согласен, что это далеко от оптимального решения, но я еще на стадии изучения Java. В идеале, как мне видится, подобное надо реализовывать в связке с БД.

Comment: Удачи в изучении. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа